# How to check Solr healthy using HAProxy

Tags: java, solr, load-balancing, high-availability, haproxy

I have 4 Solr slaves for quering, and an HAproxy to loadbalance the connections. But, sometimes the solr server stop answering requests (this is another problem that I should solve, but is a subject for another question...), but the java process does not go down, so the HAProxy still thinks the server is up and running, but the solr slave does not answer to any request. I tried this configuration for health check the solr slaves, without success, because HAProxy marked all servers as down:

```
listen  solr 0.0.0.0:10004
    mode http
    option httpchk GET /content/local/admin/ping HTTP/1.1
    balance roundrobin
    server  solr-27 192.168.1.27:8088 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3
    server  solr-36 192.168.1.36:8088 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3
    server  solr-37 192.168.1.37:8088 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3
    server  solr-38 192.168.1.38:8088 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3
```

I have also tried replacing GET for HEAD, without success.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At my company the infrastructure guys used a query rather than ping.
Considering that you have a uniqueField called id (which you most likely have), do something like:

```
/solr/select/?q=id:1234
```

It doesn't even matter if that id is not present in the index, as long as you have a field called id and the URL is correct. Even if SOLR doesn't return any documents, it will still return a 200, and that query is fast as hell.

Comment: I think this is a great approach.  I found I needed to add the ```Host``` header or my health check failed with a 400 Bad Request.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my health check was always returning 400 (Bad Request).  The problem is that HTTP 1.1 **requires** a `Host` header and I wasn't providing one.  Once I added the host header (like below), my health check started working.

```
option httpchk GET /content/local/admin/ping\ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ solr
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
option httpchk GET /content/local/admin/ping HTTP/1.0
```

HTTP/1.1 is the trouble maker.

Comment: no the troublemaker is the older version, newer versions are security improvements.